# Pyspark combine two large text files

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

I have two large text file `file_1.txt` and `file_2.txt` with some data. I want write data in those files to a single file `output.txt` in below format:

`file_1.txt`  data:

```
header info 1
header info 2
.
.
.
header info n
```

`file_2.txt`  data:

```
body info 1
body info 2
.
.
.
body info n
```

`output.txt` data:

```
header info 1
header info 2
.
.
.
header info n

body info 1
body info 2
.
.
.
body info n
```

What is the fastest way to do it using pyspark or any other python module?

### Edit:

I am using Windows 10

Comment: `cat file_1.txt file_2.txt > output.txt`

Comment: on Linux you could do `cat file1.txt file2.txt > output.txt` . As for me using pyspark to append one file to another is overcomplicated.

Comment: Thanks guys, but I am using Windows 10

Comment: then `type file_1.txt file_2.txt > output.txt` in a powershell

Comment: Union is the best option, just make sure your column names are same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a PySpark implementation.  The fastest / best joining implementation depends on the platform, file sizes, compression methodology.

You can read in the files into a single DataFrame.  Let's assume that both the files are in `some_folder`

```py
df = spark.read.text("some_folder")

df.repartition(1).write.text("some_output")
```

You could also read in the files to separate DataFrames, union the DataFrames, and then write out the result.

```py
df1 = spark.read.text("file1.txt")
df2 = spark.read.text("file1.txt")
unioned = df1.union(df2)
unioned.repartition(1).write.text("some_output")
```